# iOS 11 black screen with loading indicator

Tags: ios, iphone, ios11, ios11.1.1

In my iPhone 7 iOS 11.1.2, a black screen with spinning wheel appearing for  few seconds and asking passcode. It happening frequently in same interval. This same issue is getting in iPad too. 
Is this a problem of iOS 11 ? Anybody facing the same issue ?

all [image]

Comment: I dont understand why some one put negative rate. I am telling the fact and seeking a solution of my problem, Its better to give a solution rather than give negative rating.

Comment: I made a chat with apple support.
They give the solution is,
1. disable the automatic time and set date dec 1.
2. go to notification and disable all apps notification.

its work for me !! I wonder how it resolved. Anyway there is an update of 11.2. They told me fix available in 11.2

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't belong here as it isn't a programming question: [apple.se] might help, though. (And how on earth has this got 5 up-votes?)

Answer (score 3):

Updating to iOS 11.2 fixed the issue in my case.

I tried and failed updating via iTunes, where I got error messages.

I took the time to do my backup then I went ahead and downloaded via the phone itself the update.

This was a bit hard however since when the screen is up, the phone hangs up every so often (quite often in my case).

I then just proceeded in letting the update complete itself before attempting to open the phone. (It takes a while.)

It seems the issue was/is linked to a crash on push notifications.
In my case, shutting down all of the notifications wasn't a practical option (as seen on other boards) since I have a massive amount of apps I would have had to untoggle to not receive their notifications.

Best of luck on updating to iOS 11.2.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is an issue that most of the users face recently which re-springs the device in 30 seconds interval from 12:00 AM PST. Some problematic apps that push out notifications in regular interval causes this issue. Like OP said, **disabling notifications** will help solve this. But it is **HIGHLY RECOMMENDED** to update your OS to the most recent version or at least to 11.2 to completely fix this issue.

For more info. about this problem, check out this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-_1Tz1JazBo)** and **[this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gISNqSs-kIk)** from **Everything Apple Pro.**

**Note**: Your question is not a technical or question related to programming. You should have posted this to the respective community.

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue when setting local notifications using userNotification framework. After a lot of research I found the key problem for the issue that I was setting notifications for the date which is lesser than the current date. I set the notifications only for the future dates then the issue got solved. And this issue occurring only in iOS 11.1 . 
Hope this helps someone.

Comment: How did you do that??

Answer (score 0):

6S, iOS 11.2, Do Not Disturb does not help. Airplane mode doesn't help too (how the notifications can come in Airplane mode?!).

Installed 11.2.1 update and it helped.

But here's how my notifications look like now - https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8nN7.jpg